# How to get rid of the risks posed by port forwarding?

Tags: networking, port

I want to open a server on my computer, which requires to open a certain port to allow traffic to it.

The only problem is, the traffic might be malicious, and install some nasty software on my computer and take control over it.

How can I open a port, and only allow legitimate traffic through it, blocking people from hacking into my computer by exploiting the open port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be pessimistic but the truth is this is a question that thousands of system administrators would love to be able to say they have the answer to, and if there were a straight forward answer, penetration testers around the world would be out of a job. The short typical answer would be to tell you to keep whatever application that is running on that port up to date and patched consistently, but that doesn't prevent someone with a zero-day from exploiting the service. Furthermore, if you don't know the software that you are configuring, you may have left open a security risk. Make sure you understand everything about the service you set up or you may be introducing security holes.

TLDR: There's no easy way to ensure that only legitimate traffic traverses your port.